# Implementing binary arithmetic encoder

Tags: algorithms, data-compression

I have set integers that are normally distributed, and I'm trying to implement binary arithmetic encoding, as suggested in this post: [Compressing normally distributed data](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/20156/compressing-normally-distributed-data)

I'm running into trouble because the user remarks that we should try arithmetic encoding the quotient using a sequence of binary symbols. I don't understand what this means because I've only seen arithmetic encoders operate on sequences. I'm aware that BAC can work on multi-symbol alphabets, but I'm still unsure of how to implement that.

Could anyone explain a rough guideline of how a binary arithmetic coder would be implemented for this type of data or as explained in the linked question?

Comment: Arithmetic coding is difficult because you need infinite precision, and you don't have that. I recommend first writing a decoder, then creating an encoder that generates the bits that the decoder can correctly decode.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Do you know what the user means though when he/she says "arithmetic encode the quotient using a sequence of binary variables?"